# Check if coupon code already exist in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, coupon-codes

I try to create a code to generate a lot of coupon code randomly, but the problem is i need to check if the coupon code already exist or not, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected $_coupon;
```

in `construct` add this

```
   public function __construct(     
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon $coupon
    ) {
        $this->_coupon = $coupon;
    }
```

Now you can use like this,

```
 $ruleId=   $this->_coupon->loadByCode($couponCode)->getRuleId();

 if (empty($ruleId)) {
            // generate coupon code
        }
```

Where `$couponCode` is  your coupon code

Comment: so if the `$ruleId` is empty, my coupon code is valid?

Comment: Yes ...... , @Hunter

Comment: this worked for me

Comment: how to get all list of coupon codes which can apply on cart page in magento 2